# error 403, webscraping project, using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am doing and online internship in web scraping for this website:   https://www.proflowers.com/blog/types-of-flowers/,

A website of flowers and their main points, but the scraping has resulted in no data, i have added debugging functions and this was the result:  **[image: Error accessing the website: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url]**

so my question is this part of the training that some websites can't be accessed ? or there is something i can do to pypass this issue?

I have attached screenshot of my code, please advise, thanks in advance

Comment: DO NOT attach screenshots of code and errors.  Instead, cut-and-paste the code directly into the question.  Otherwise, we would have to retype it all, and none of us are going to do that.

Comment: Yes, it's quite common for web sites to reject queries from application that are not actually browsers, to prevent people from stealing their copyrighted info.  There are ways to "fake" your browser ID.  Also, you're not providing a certificate for an HTTPS request.

Comment: A 403 error means the website doesn't want to talk to you.  Maybe it thinks you're a robot, or maybe it doesn't like your IP domain address, or maybe a hundred other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `User-Agent` HTTP header when you're accessing the site:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0"
}

url = "https://www.proflowers.com/blog/types-of-flowers"

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(resp)


soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.h1.text)
```

Prints:

```
<Response [200]>
151 Types of Flowers Common in the U.S.
```